# Uniform initialization syntax or type conversion?

Tags: c++11, type-conversion, uniform-initialization

Changing the parens to curly braces seems to produce the exact same behavior in my program, even though semantically they seem to be quite different beasts. Is there a reason (memory usage, performance, etc.) to prefer one?

```
double pie = 3.14159;

myVal = int(pie); // type conversion using operator()
myVal = int{pie}; // uniform initialization syntax
```

[edit]

My actual code is a little different from the above example, perhaps that explains the narrowing issues:

```
int32_t result;

myVal = uint16_t(result);  // myVal is between 0 and 65535
myVal = uint16_t{result};  // myVal is between 0 and 65535
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First note that what you are doing there is not initialization, is a type conversion followed by an assignment. I strongly recommend C++ casting operators (`static_cast` in this case) over C casts and these constructor-based castings.

That said, the main difference between uniform initialization and the other is that uniform initialization *doesn't allow* (See the note) narrowing conversions such these you are doing, float to int. This is helpful when writting constants or initializing variables, since initializing an `int` with `3.141592654` has no sense at all because the fractional part will be stripped out.

**NOTE:** I remember the initial proposal for uniform-initialization explicitly stating that it **disallows narrowing conversions**, so if I had understood it correctly, code like yours should not compile.
[I have tested it](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/aaf1a0b0d839f7b4) and seems like compilers emmit warnings about the narrowing conversions instead of aborting compilation. Indeed, that warnings are useful too, and you could allways use a `-Werror` flag.

Comment: There's also something about uniform-initialization and implicit conversion constructors too, but I can't quite recall it